# Why do the ajax tags send their request twice?

Tags: jquery, struts2

I have a number of forms used to create entities in my system. They all were working fine until i turned them into dialog boxes using jquery. Now they call their respective actions twice.

This is an example of one of the forms jsp:

```
<div class="dialog" id="crear_proyecto_dialog" title="Crear proyecto">
    <s:form action='crear_proyecto'>
        ...
        <sx:submit id="crear_proyecto_submit" targets="ventana_mensaje_proyecto" value="Create ..."/>
    </s:form>
</div>
```

If this form is placed in the index.jsp without any more changes, it works fine. But then I added this to the javascript of the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen:false,
            modal:true,
            draggable:true,
            closeText:"x"
    });
...
}
```

To turn it into a dialog box, and now the 'crear_proyecto' action is called twice once the form is submitted. Does anybody have any idea how could I fix this?

Comment: I'm a bit confused; you're using the Dojo Ajax tags, *and* adding jQuery events to them?

Comment: Those are forms that make inserts into the database using ajax. I need those forms to be shown in dialog boxes but that's making the request being called twice.

Comment: Ah, misunderstood/misread. I'm personally *very* leery of doing *anything* non-Dojo-related to Dojo widgets, *particularly* since it's such an ancient version of Dojo. IMO, since you're using jQuery anyway, either use the jQuery plugin, or just use plain jQuery. The Dojo tags have been deprecated since S2.1, and in this case, I don't see a good reason to bother with it.